# Reports in Command Line FitNesse

Tags: command-line, automated-tests, fitnesse

How do I generate reports from Command Line FitNesse ?

And, what types of reports are possible?
xml, txt, plain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only formats allowed are xml, html plain text end. But the documentation is bad, there's no page about this.. =(

Answer (score 1):

Best bet is to use cURL or wget and call Fitnesse through its RESTful services.

http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.AdministeringFitNesse.RestfulServices

XML is the most common format, although I think JSON is available for some actions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this page didn't exist back in 2010, but there is a command line parameter to run a test and exit:

http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.AdministeringFitNesse.CommandLineArguments

```
-c <command>: Run a Rest Command and then exit.
```

Where the "command" is a REST command just like you could pass to cUrl.  This works in Windows or Linux and does not depend on cUrl. The list of REST commands can be found [here](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.AdministeringFitNesse.RestfulServices).

I still cannot find a page that lists all available formats for test/suite output, but there is a page showing the [XML Format](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.AdministeringFitNesse.RestfulServices.RestfulSuiteXmlFormat).  The other formats available are ["text"](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.AdministeringFitNesse.ControllingFitNesseFromTheCommandLine) (`format=text`) and HTML, which is the default.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, use cURL or wget.

For example, to run a suite called "MySuite" and get a report in XML, the URL to use is:
http://ip:port/MySuite?suite&format=xml

For a single test called "MyTest", the URL changes to:
http://ip:port/MyTest?test&format=xml